# Is there a simple way to put NSLocalizedStrings in an array using swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, nslocalizedstring

I want to add an array of localized strings as datasource for a collection view in a swift application.

I have written this :

```
let text = [NSLocalizedString("s0",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s1",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s2",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s3",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s4",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s5",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s6",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s7",comment: ""),NSLocalizedString("s8",comment: "")]
```

Is there a more simple way to put all the strings in the array, because I have 1000 localized strings and this does not look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set your strings with a format (s%d.4 , for instance) and build your array around that format.

```
var text:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

for index in 1...10 {
    let formattedString = String(format: "s%.4d", index)

    let localizedString = NSLocalizedString(formattedString, comment: "comment")

    text.addObject(localizedString)
}
```

Then you declare your strings like: s0001, s0002, s0003, etc.

Comment: Thanks @tiago-almeida unfortunetly the first line gives me: Type annotation missing in pattern, and if I change it to 'var text: String' it says that: 'Cannot invoke NSLocalizedString with an argument list of type(String)'

Comment: Hi @Eduard, had to use a playground to fix the code :). I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Realized you could write this in two steps and not three. Simplified my answer.

## Write a helper function to localize the array

```
public func Localized(_ key: String) -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
}
```

## Call it using map

```
// for example
       let localized = ["s0", "s1", "s2"].map { Localized($0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it like that:

**HelperClass**:

```
static func getLocalized(withKey key: String, targetSpecific:Bool) -> String{

    if targetSpecific{
        return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName:"TargetSpecific", comment: "")
    }
    else{
        return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
    }
}

static func getLocalizedArray(withKey key: String, targetSpecific:Bool) -> [String]{

    return getLocalized(withKey: key, targetSpecific: targetSpecific).components(separatedBy: ",")

}
```

**Localizable.string**

```
"optionsArray" = "Show devices,Add device";
```

So you can call it like that:

```
let optionsArray:[String] = AppHelper.getLocalizedArray(withKey: "optionsArray", targetSpecific: false)
```